# Iterating column data in row iteration

Tags: python, csv, python-3.7

I am making a loop of random numbers, but also want to loop in an already available column of data from another file.

Simplified example:

```
out = /location/of/test.txt
file = open(out,'w')

var = [7,12,1,35,4]

for num in range(5):
    a = randint(1,10)
    file.write('%i ' % a)

    b = randint(1,10)
    file.write('%i ' % b)

file.write('\n')
```

The result I want is:

```
4   10  7
10  8   12
7   2   1
6   5   35
9   8   4
```

My problem is, how to I loop in my var array into my code?

I tried something like:

```
for num in range(5):
    a = randint(1,10)
    file.write('%i ' % a)

    b = randint(1,10)
    file.write('%i ' % b)

    for c in var:
       file.write('%i ' % c)

file.write('\n')
```

But the result would be:

```
4   10  7 12 1 35 4
10  8   7 12 1 35 4
7   2   7 12 1 35 4
6   5   7 12 1 35 4
9   8   7 12 1 35 4
```

I understand why that is the result, I just don't know how to iterate through my var as well as the generated numbers loop to create the format I want.

Comment: You just need one loop, the c in var loop, then do your a,b,c logic.

Comment: My question was over simplified. you are correct as I have tried your tip for practice. I have updated my question to be closer to my original problem.

Comment: My tip is still valid even with your updated question.  You have 5 variables in c.  So doing a num in range 5 isn't needed.  Just remove the num in range and put c in var in it's place and keep the rest of the logic the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
out = /location/of/test.txt
file = open(out,'w')

df = some dataframe
df[:,4] = [7,12,1,35,4]

for col in range(len(df.index)):
    a = randint(1,10)
    file.write('%i ' % a)

    b = randint(1,10)
    file.write('%i ' % b)

    c = (df.iloc[[col],4])
    file.write('%.i ' % c)

    file.write('\n')
```

Comment: You need to accept this as the answer if this is the solution to your question.

Answer (score 1):

You don't use `num` anywhere, so just iterate over `var` directly. I also recommend you use a `with` clause with `open` and utilize f-strings, which are available in Python 3.6+:

```
out = 'test.txt'
var = [12,12,12,12,12]
a, b = 10, 11

with open(out, 'w') as fin:
    for val in var:
        fin.write(f'{a} {b} {val}\n')
```

Output:

```
10 11 12
10 11 12
10 11 12
10 11 12
10 11 12
```

Comment: This works, but i might have over simplified my question. a and b are random numbers and c is an array from another file. I will update my post.

Comment: I saw one of your replies to iterating a dataframe through pandas, and that helped me solve my issue.

Comment: @MasonJ., Good to know. Feel free to self-answer your question. It's actually encouraged and may help someone else!

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm misunderstanding you, this should be the way it should be written.  You have 5 variables in the var array.  Loop through the array and do the rest of the logic below it.

```
out = /location/of/test.txt
file = open(out,'w')

var = [7,12,1,35,4]

for c in var:
    a = randint(1,10)
    file.write('%i ' % a)

    b = randint(1,10)
    file.write('%i ' % b)

    file.write('%i ' % c)

    file.write('\n')
```